# Using Mustache.js to Embed Raw JSON

Tags: mustache

I am using mustache on the command line to embed a JSON object inside of `<script>` tags within an HTML object.

`cat sampleData.json | mustache - man_report.mustache > output.html`

Sample data looks like this:

```
{"report_type":"total_by_age_group",
"data":[{"age_group":"Age 41 - 65","percent":41.04},
        {"age_group":"Age Over 66","percent":19.11},
        {"age_group":"Age < 18 Or Invalid Birth Date","percent":0.00},      
        {"age_group":"Age 18 - 25","percent":8.03},
        {"age_group":"Age 26 - 40","percent":31.82}]}
```

Which is what I would like to also see in the resultant HTML file.

report.mustache looks like:

`reportObject = {{data}}`

output.html looks like this:

`reportObject = [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]`

I just want the exact same JSON as I started with. Any ideas?

Comment: I ended up doing this with PHP... which is the first PHP script I've ever written.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A little bit old, but this was the first question that came up when I did a search. I found an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15580946/1961413

If you are able to preprocess the data, you could stringifiy it. This would make it a string that could be embedded:

```
var sampleData = JSON.stringify(sampleData);
```

Once you've done this you need to ensure that Mustache doesn't HTMLize the string (triple up the handlebars):

```
var reportObject = {{{.}}};
```

You can then access it in you webpage:

```
alert(reportObject.report_type);
for($data in reportObject.data){
     alert(JSON.stringify(reportObject.data[$data]));
}
```

Comment: I'm a bit passed being able to test this, but your answer makes sense so I am going to accept it.

Comment: Thank-you, though I wouldn't have worried about it. It was more a note for myself, and the next person to ask the question.