# Mustache not rendering JSON value as JSON encoded string

Tags: json, haskell, mustache

The full example is here:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
module Test2 where

import Data.Aeson
import Text.Mustache

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let example = Data.Aeson.object [ "key" .= (5 :: Integer), "somethingElse" .= (2 :: Integer) ]
  print . encode $ example
  print ("Start" :: String)
  case compileTemplate "" "{{{jsonData}}}" of
    Right x -> do
      print $ substituteValue x (Text.Mustache.object ["jsonData" ~= example])
    Left e -> error . show $ e
```

The above produces the following output:

```
"{\"somethingElse\":2,\"key\":5}"
"Start"
"fromList [(\"somethingElse\",2.0),(\"key\",5.0)]"
```

My expectation is it would produce:

```
"{\"somethingElse\":2,\"key\":5}"
"Start"
"{\"somethingElse\":2,\"key\":5}"
```

Comment: Which mustache library do you use? mustache or stache?

Comment: I'm using mustache 2.1.2

Comment: I can't reproduce your output – the first line is missing. Can you fix that?

Comment: Apologies, I added an extra print and forgot to update the code. It should now produce the output as stated (from within GHCi).

Comment: I think this could be a bug in mustache. I suggest you open an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mustache doesn't seem to support straight substitution of JSON objects. Setting up a similar example [here](http://mustache.github.io/#demo), I receive

> [object Object]

as output. Not identical to yours, but it indicates that the issue is not necessarily with the Haskell implementation.

In other words, I believe the issue is with your template `{{{jsonData}}}`.

If you change it to `{{{jsonData.somethingElse}}}`, it works fine (I know this is not what you want).

Alternatively, encode the JSON data as text prior to passing it to the substitution function as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34721836/using-mustache-js-to-embed-raw-json). Basically something like this:

```
substituteValue x (Text.Mustache.object ["jsonData" ~= (encodeToLazyText jsonData)])
```

This results in your desired output. `encodeToLazyText` is found in `Data.Aeson.Text`.

Working code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Main where

import           Data.Aeson ((.=))
import qualified Data.Aeson as A
import           Data.Aeson.Text (encodeToLazyText)
import           Text.Mustache ((~=))
import qualified Text.Mustache as M
import qualified Text.Mustache.Types as M

main :: IO ()
main = do
  print . A.encode $ jsonData
  putStrLn "Start"
  case M.compileTemplate "" "in mustache: {{{jsonData}}}" of
    Right template ->
      print (M.substituteValue template mustacheVals)
    Left e -> 
      error . show $ e

jsonData :: A.Value
jsonData = 
  A.object
    [ "key" .= (5 :: Integer)
    , "somethingElse" .= (2 :: Integer)
    ]

mustacheVals :: M.Value
mustacheVals =
  M.object
    [ "jsonData" ~= encodeToLazyText jsonData
    ]
```

Comment: I incorrectly assumed the JSON functionality had to do with rendering JSON values.