# Mustache inside of href

Tags: javascript, templates, mustache

I have JSON like this:

```
 { "something": "http://something.com" }
```

and HTML like this:

```
 <a href="{{something}}">{{something}}</a>
```

When I apply Mustache, I get

```
 <a href="%7B%7Bsomething%7D%7D">http://something.com</a>
```

But what I am trying to get is

```
 <a href="http://something.com">http://something.com</a>
```

I already tried `{{{ something}}}`, `{{& something}}`, single quotes, double quotes...  I even read documentation.

Can you help me?

Comment: Triple curly braces are also needed here to prevent escaping of "://"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure your template source is straight text - don't try and grab parsed HTML source as your template. Browsers will urlencode/escape those characters in your link href, and result in those `%7Bs` and `%7Ds` you see in your code. Mustache won't recognize that.

I suppose unescaping the source you pass to mustache might work, though.

```
Mustache.render(unescape(source),view)
```

Comment: Thanks! Unescaping actually helped.
Turns out I was using jQuery to do some transformation with template before feeding it to Mustache (I basically did something like this: $("<a href="{{something}}">{{something}}</a>") ), that's why this piece of HTML become escaped

Answer (score 17):

I think you need to make use of the `&` for escaping in combination with surrounding your template with a template script:

```
<script type="text/template" id="tmpl">
    <a href="{{& something }}">{{ something }}</a>
</script>
```

Found this example [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8137794/74757).

Comment: Additionally triple braces - `{{{ something }}}` is an alternate syntax