# VueJS - Looping through a list inside a vue component makes empty list

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I asked a question yesterday and none of the answers are working so I decided to start a fresh one with more details.

You can view the question here: [VueJS - using mustache template strings inside href attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55287776/vuejs-using-mustache-template-strings-inside-href-attribute)

Basically I have a vue app split out into components. That project structure looks like below:

[image]

Inside my "Nav.vue" component, I have a navigation that I want to loop through inside a data block.

The entire code of the component looks like this:

```
<template>
    <div>
<header class="global-header">
  <div class="global-header__container">
    <h1>NAV IS HERE</h1>
    <nav class="nav-main" role="navigation" aria-label="Site">
      <ul>
        <li v-for="menuItem in menuItems" class="nav-item">
          <a
            :href="menuItem.url"
            class="nav-link"
            >{{ menuItems.text }}</a
          >
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
</div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'Nav',
  data: function() {
    return {
      menuItems: [
        {text: 'Item 1', url: '/item-1'},
        {text: 'Item 2', url: '/item-2'},
        {text: 'Item 3', url: '/item-3'},
        {text: 'Item 4', url: '/item-4'}
      ]
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

In the answers of the previous question I have done everything suggested:

1. making data a function
2. using proper syntax for link `<a :href="menuItem.url" class="nav-link">{{ menuItems.text }}</a>`
3. fixing the typo in menu items.

However, my `<ul>` is totally empty after all those suggestions. Why?

My App.vue looks like this:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <router-view/>
  </div>
</template>

<style lang="scss">

</style>
```

main.js looks like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

router.js looks like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Home from './views/Home.vue'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: Home
    },
    {
      path: '/about',
      name: 'about',
      // route level code-splitting
      // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
      // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
      component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ './views/About.vue')
    }
  ]
})
```

With all that shared - do I need to put my data somewhere else? Why is my `<ul>` empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this part of the code:

```
<ul>
        <li v-for="menuItem in menuItems" class="nav-item">
          <a
            :href="menuItem.url"
            class="nav-link"
            >{{ menuItems.text }}</a
          >
        </li>
      </ul>
```

You have to change `menuItems.text` to `menuItem.text`.

Comment: Ah yes! Thank you.